# PHP with onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, syntax, onclick

I want to execute a javascript function from a php file

Like:

```
<?php

$type=0;
echo('<img onclick="alert('.$type.')" src="picture.jpg"/>');

?>
```

Result : ok everything is workin. Now i want to do it with a string:

```
<?php

$type='e';
echo('<img onclick="alert('.$type.')" src="picture.jpg"/>');

?>
```

Result : Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not definedonclick @ loadPlayer2.php:2

```
<?php

$type='e';
echo('<img onclick="alert("'.$type.'")" src="picture.jpg"/>');

?>
```

Result : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

```
    <?php

$type='e';
echo('<img onclick="alert(\"'.$type.'\")" src="picture.jpg"/>');

    ?>
```

Result : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

```
<?php

$type='\e';

echo('<img onclick="alert("$type")" src="picture.jpg"/>');



?>
```

Result : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Answer (score 3):

Different **contexts** require different escaping. You are mixing PHP strings with HTML attributes and JavaScript strings.

1. [String interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) only works in double quotes:

   ```
             alternate single+dbl quotes
                        ↓
     echo "<img onclick='alert(\"$type\")' src='picture.jpg'>"
                               ↑
                        escaped quote
   ```
2. The `$type` variable can be transformed from a PHP String to a JS string per [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode):

   ```
     $type = json_encode($type);
     echo "<img onclick='alert($type)' src='picture.jpg'>"
                                 ↑
               adds "double" quotes automatically
   ```
3. And it's best to apply [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) for the whole attribute:

   ```
     $type = json_encode($type);
     $onclick = htmlspecialchars("alert($type)");
     echo "<img onclick='$onclick' src='picture.jpg'>"
                            ↑
               escapes `"` into `&quot;`
   ```
4. So the resulting output should look like:

   ```
      <img onclick='alert(&quot;\\e&quot;)' src='picture.jpg'>
                                                             ↑
                                                     pseudo-XHTML begone
   ```

   And at this point, one could even use `"` for the attribute values again.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
<?php

$type="e";

echo('<img onclick="alert(\''.$type.'\')" src="picture.jpg"/>');


?>
```